# Save and retrieve data "by date" using Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to figure out how to save data "by date" in Core Data using Swift 2.0. In SQL I would want something like

`select sum(amount) from X where date = 'date'`

To accomplish this, I would need to

```
1. Record the time/date an item was added
2. Define some line of code that will function like the SQL statement above
```

I'm not sure how to do either of these. I've looked around online at Apple's documentation but didn't see anything. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 1. Use `[NSDate date]` at the moment of saving. 2. `NSPredicate`

Comment: You will need to retrieve the required objects from core data and then loop over them to compute the sum.  Have you read the core data programming guide? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSExpressionDescription`:

```
NSExpressionDescription *sumAmountDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
sumAmountDescription.name = @"sumAmount";
sumAmountDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];
sumAmountDescription.expressionResultType = NSInteger32AttributeType;

NSDate *date = <your date>;

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"<entity name here>"];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@", date];
request.propertiesToFetch = @[sumAmountDescription];

NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSDictionary *values = result.firstObject;
NSNumber *sumAmount = values[@"sumAmount"];
```